# Challenging probability and statistics problems?

Tags: probability, statistics

The books I have on the subject lack entertaining problems. Can someone suggest a book with more challenging problems - perhaps not at olympiad level, but a bit easier. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the book *Understanding Probability* written by Henk Tijms